# Group.find results in "Coudn't find Group with 'id'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let me say something to begin with - I am very new to ruby on rails as a lot of users here are. So don't throw stones at me, please :)
I am trying to create an API application on Ruby for my android application. Here what I have a problem with:

**user.rb Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :tasks
  has_secure_password
end
```

And here is **group.rb Model**:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And **UserController.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @group = Group.find(params.require(:user).permit(:group))
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @group.users.create(@user)
    @group.users.save
    # @user.save!
    render json: @user
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

where I want to create a new user.
I've already tried to create user with `@user.create(user_params)` but it says, that group doesn't exist, so now I am trying to do that via `@group.users.create` but exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#create` keeps coming up, saying that it couldn't find Group with `id={"id"=>1020};`

The last thing I have to show is JSON that i send:

```
{
  "group": {
    "id":1020
  },
  "user": {
    "name": "volkeee",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "123",
    "repeat_password": "123"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to change your `@group` to `Group.find(params['group']['id'])`.

Comment: already tried that and here's what comes up: "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument"

Comment: This group with said ID exists, because when I send request to /groups a lot of entries appears as JSON array and 1020 is there.

Comment: @Volkeee what are you trying to do?    create group with associated users?

Comment: @krishnar I am trying to create a new user under a group

Comment: @Volkeee check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly create a new private method for group params like

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:id)
end
```

replace

```
@group = Group.find(params.require(:user).permit(:group))
```

with

```
@group_params = group_params
@group = Group.find(@group_params[:id])
```

I'm not in front of a PC so cant actually test. But this should work. Let me know if this doesn't.

**A better approach**

Replace

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@group.users.create(@user)
@group.users.save
```

with

```
@user = @group.users.new(user_params)
@user.save
```

This is a much cleaner and rails way

Comment: ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in UsersController#create: unknown attribute "group_id" for User
Probably I am missing something...

Comment: Can you make sure your association is correct? Does your `User` model has the group_id column in it or is it vice-versa?

Comment: Also, in which line are you getting this error? Can you make sure if you're able to fetch the group now? A `puts @group.inspect` should do. Just to make sure

Comment: "@user = @group.users.new(user_params)" this line produces said error;
User model has no "group_id" field. I am going to create one via new migration.
I've commented the saving process of user and place puts instead of that. Response is 1 word - null

Comment: Response is 1 word - null - is this for `puts @group.inspect`?

Comment: What does `@group_params = group_params` and then `puts @group_params[:id]` give you? Are you getting the id in the logs?

Comment: Thats where you problem is. Can you share your params again please? The whole thing

Comment: There is a "Content-Type" application-json header and the request body is {   "group": {     "id":"1020"   },   "user": {     "name": "volkeee",     "email": "test@gmail.com",     "password": "123",     "repeat_password": "123"   } }

Comment: Can you try replacing `@group_params[:id]` in  `@group = Group.find(@group_params[:id])` with `@group_params["id"]` and see if you get the `id` displayed in the logs.

Comment: Everything was working properly after I created the group_id field via new migration. There was nothing wrong with the parameters I simply forgot to remove "render json: @user" - it caused the response to include "null" in it, so I thought the parameters are not visible for some reason. 
Also it wasn't clear for me what "puts" does. The code was working properly already when you told me test "puts".

I am sorry for being such an idiot :) I am going to accept this answer as correct if my reputation will allow to do that. Thank you a lot, @Aakanksha

Comment: @Volkeee, No worries, happy to help. Hope the functionality of `puts` is now clear. There is one suggestion though. 

The main benefit of working in Rails is convention. I suggest you get clear with the basics if you're new and start working on the clean and conventional code. The Rails community is very large and eager to guide you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: can I reach you personally somewhere with one more question?

Comment: Sure, Please reach me [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156035/rails-group-id-not-found-issues). We can discuss your issue and i'll try my best to answer :) I might not be available right now but i'll keep an eye on it and get back to you ASAP

Comment: I had an issue when wrote a message here, but I already resolved that and don't even remember what that was. 
Right now I want to create custom route for existing model. It should be a simple route to check whether user already exist in database. And it would be great to know in general how to create own custom routes.

Comment: I am unable to use chat yet cause I need more rep :(

Answer (score 0):

**Change your create method like below**

```
def create
  @group = Group.find_or_create_by(params[:group][:id]) do | group |
            group.assign_attributes(group_params)
           end
  @user = @group.users.create(user_params)

  render json: @user
end
```

**create private method**

```
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:id, :name, :has_subgroups, :created_at, :updated_at)
end
```

**NOTE**: user table should have group_id column

Comment: ArgumentError in UsersController#create: Unsupported argument type: 1020 (Integer)

Comment: Change the json to `"id":"1020"`.

Comment: this is how Group looks like {"id":1020,"name":"НІ-16-1","has_subgroups":true,"created_at":"2017-09-29T10:14:08.000Z","updated_at":"2017-09-29T10:14:08.000Z"}

Comment: @krishnar I will try your solution if the Aakanksha`s answer wont work